# ggplot: manual color assignment for single variable only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot:

```
ggplot(data3, aes(year, NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG, color = country)) + geom_line() + 
  xlab('Year') + ylab('GDP per capita')
  labs(title = "Annual GDP Growth rate (%)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now I want to change color and line thickness (black, and a about 30% thicker than others) for one variable only (for one country only).

I have found how to manually assign colors for all variables, but not how to do it for only one. Also, graph can have different number of variables (countries), depending on input data.

Comment: hint for the image: you can add it as a link and someone with more reputation can add it after!

Comment: Thanks, if you were the one who upvoted my question, I think you gave me enough reputation to post image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit difficult without some reproducible data, but you should be able to achieve this by adding a `geom_line()` that only uses the data for that specific country:

```
ggplot(data3, aes(year, NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG, color = country)) + geom_line() + 
  xlab('Year') + ylab('GDP per capita') +
labs(title = "Annual GDP Growth rate (%)") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=subset(data3, country == "China"), colour="black", size=1.5)
```

Keeping the legend in line with the colour and size is a bit trickier- you can do it by manually hacking at the legend with `override.aes`, but it's not necessarily the most elegant solution:

```
# Needed to access hue_pal(), which is where ggplot's
# default colours come from
library(scales)

ggplot(data3, aes(year, NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG, color = country)) + geom_line() + 
  xlab('Year') + ylab('GDP per capita') +
  labs(title = "Annual GDP Growth rate (%)") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=subset(data3, country == "World"), colour="black", size=1.5) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(
    colour=c(hue_pal()(11)[1:10], "black"), size=c(rep(1, 10), 1.5))))
```

Comment: Hi, when I do that, I only get that one variable (line in the plot), and nothing else. I have added my entire code for reproducibility (data come from WDI library, so no need to generate it)

Comment: @user1754606: The problem may have just been a missing `+` after `ylab()`, I noticed that once I had your code.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, while the line changed to black in the graph, label in the legend is still the color it was before. How do I change legend to black as well?

Comment: @user1754606: See my edit. You can do it, but it's not necessarily pretty.