# Ggplot2: how to set color for a single value and leave the others to auto color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use line graphs that I made with the ggplot2 package. My question now: How can I define a color for a single value and leave the rest to "auto color"?

The graph I'm talking about: [image: Graph (link to imgur)]

What I want is for the "Summe" to be black and for the rest to stay the same.

The code for the graph:

```
ggplot(data = ICU_Cephalosporine_SU_Per100PatientDays_norest_nototal_long, aes(x = Monat, y = `SUs pro 100 Pflegetage`, colour = `API`, group = API)) + geom_line(size = 1) + geom_point(size = 2)
```

What I have tried to add:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c(name = "Summe", values = "#000000"))
```

and

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("Summe" = "#E08214"))
```

The first resultet in the error:

> Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 2 provided.

And the second one:

> Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 1 provided.

I'm not able to find the solution, does anybody have an idea how I'm able to do this?

EDIT:
I created some sample data and applied my new findings so far:

```
mydata <- data.frame("Letter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
"A", "B", "C", "D"), "Month" = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb",
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr"), "Number" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3,
6, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7))


ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Month, y = Number, colour = Letter, group = Letter))
+ theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
+ geom_line(data=subset(mydata, Letter == "A"), colour="black", size = 1)
+ geom_line(data=subset(mydata, Letter != "A"), size = 1)
+ geom_point(data=subset(mydata, Letter == "A"), colour="black", size = 1.5)
+ geom_point(data=subset(mydata, Letter != "A"), size = 1.5)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Month, y = Number, colour = Letter, group = Letter))
+ theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
+ geom_line()
+ geom_point(size = 1.5)
```

My new problem is, that now "A" is not beeing displayed in the legend anymore. Why? The data was subset after the aes()?!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894102/change-color-of-only-one-bar-in-ggplot) could help.

Comment: can you provide some sample data so that we can provide well phrased code snippets?

Comment: Another [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896039/ggplot-manual-color-assignment-for-single-variable-only)

Comment: I was able to use some of the information given here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896039/ggplot-manual-color-assignment-for-single-variable-only) (thanks @VivekKalyanarangan). But now the highlighted / black value is not beeing displayed in the legend anymore. Does anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard palette ggplot uses (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette/8197703#8197703))

```
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}
```

You can do something like

```
pal <- gg_color_hue(4)
pal[4] <- "#E08214"
ggplot(...) +
   ... +
   scale_color_manual(values=pal)
```

Comment: You could also mention that you copied hue code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197703/1286528)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is that I really would like to be able to assign a color to a certain value (in the newly provided sample data "A"), because I have many different plots that have different amounts of values but have all the value "A", or "Summe" respectively, in common.